# Facebook PHP SDK v4 - Post to page feed not showing correctly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've got a facebook app that has been approved for the following permissions:
'publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'public_profile'
The app works in so far as it asks for login, creates token, and posts to a page without an error - however despite the logged in user being an admin for the page it's posting too, the posts are hidden by default, and you have to go and make them visible via the activity log page in facebook.

Having done that they are only visible in the left hand side 'posts' box, rather than the main page feed, and then not to everyone.

What I'm wanting is to have the posts go through directly to the page's main feed and be visible to everyone. Any help with this is appreciated.

I'm posting using the following parameters:

```
$params =  array(   
        'access_token'  => $access_token,
        'name'          => $articles_name,
        'link'          => $articles_url,
        'description'   => (strlen($message)>255) ? substr($message,0,250).'...' : $message,
        'message'       => $articles_url,
        'caption'       => $articles_name,
        'picture'       => (strlen($articles_image_url)) ? $articles_image_url : '',
        'published'     => true,
        'actions' => array(
                            'name'=> $articles_name,
                            'link'=> $articles_url
                   ),
        );
```

This is then (successfully) submitted as follows:

```
$post = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/'.$page_id.'/feed', $params))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: Use a page access token

Comment: Brilliantly spotted - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WizKid has pointed out - I was not using a page token - just the token for the page admin.
Simply doing the following sort out the issues:

```
$page_access_token = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$page_id, array( 'fields' => 'access_token' ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
$params['access_token'] = $page_access_token['access_token'];
```